# Spring MVC store user object in session after login and retrieve it from jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to store logged in user object in spring MVC session and retrieve it from jsp page. I have created `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler` from extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and on `handle` method, i am storing simple variable in session.

```
@Override
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException {
   String targetUrl ="/dashboard";

   HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
   session.setAttribute("userEmail", "damith.uwu@gmail.com");

   if (response.isCommitted()) {
      System.out.println("Can't redirect");
      return;
   }
       redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
```

Inside my jsp page

```
<c:if test="${not empty userEmail}">
    ${userEmail}
</c:if>
```

But it is always getting empty.

My questions are,

- Is this the correct way or best way to store logged in user variable?
- Is there any alternative way to complete this?

Thank you.

Comment: Spring Security already stores the user in the session... Just use that..

Comment: Yes. But i want to add custom user object in session.